# Why is my private enum still visible to other classes

Tags: c#

I have an enum `_levels` which is declared as private but it's still accessible to other classes.
What I want is to access it by using a property.

Please consider my code below.

Thanks.

```
public sealed class TestClass
{
    private static TestClass instance = new TestClass();
    private enum _levels { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, ASE, SE, SSE, TL, AM };                  

    public TestClass(){}

    public static TestClass Instance
    {
     get { return instance; }
    }   

    public _levels Levels
    {
        get { return _levels; }         
    }
}
```

Comment: you made it public by returning it as a public property...

Comment: Your code won't even compile, precisely because the `_levels` enum is less accessible than the `Levels` property. Are you saying that you want it to be accessible?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this does even compile. I'd expect an inconsistent accessibility error.

Comment: I think you will find that the code will still error when built. *Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'ConsoleApplication8.TestClass._levels' is less accessible than property 'ConsoleApplication8.TestClass.Levels'*

Comment: You are also returning a type from the getter of `Levels`, which shouldn't compile either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
public sealed class TestClass
{
    public enum Levels { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, ASE, SE, SSE, TL, AM };                  

    private Levels _levels; 
    public Levels Levels
    {
        get { return _levels; }         
    }

    private static TestClass instance = new TestClass();
    public static TestClass Instance
    {
     get { return instance; }
    }   

    public TestClass(){}
}
```

Comment: @yonan2236, keep in mind that when you declare an enum, you declare a type, and not an instance of that type :)

Comment: @vc74 correct, but why my inner type (nested under a outer class as per above code) has to be visible or be public for the class. Any ways he is creating a property to access its instance with in the same class. Why this rule? its confusing.

Comment: @yonan2236, It's only because your property is public that you have to make the enum public. Otherwise it could be private         private enum Levels { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, ASE, SE, SSE, TL, AM };             private Levels Levels
    {
        get { return _levels; }         
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition makes no sense, as the definition of the enum type is less accessible than the property with that type.

The type definition has to be at least as visible as the usage (in your case a property) of that type.

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a type. You can't use type as a variable.